# LocalDateTime with Joda-Time showing with next month of date

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jodatime

I am working on Spring Framework project. I am using **spring-boot-dependencies 1.3.5.RELEASE**. This internally using **jackson-datatype-joda [Jackson.version]** 2.7.4. and **joda-time** : 2.8.2 and **jersey** : 2.22.2

I am storing value of LocalDateTime into a db table column createDate [**TimeStamp**(6)].

I am using @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class) and  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
on createDate field, to serialize and deserialize the datatime value.

But when I am trying to show the stored date on UI, its showing me date of next month.

**For example:** 
Suppose, I am storing the datetime value "13-**JUN**-16 7:15:25 pm" in db, but when I try to get the value of the field for showing on UI, it showing me "**7**/13/2016 7:15:25 pm". *It is showing me date of next month.*

Note: Same code was working with dropwizard framework where I was using Joda-Time: 2.2, jackson-datatype-joda[Jackson-version]: 2.2.3

I also tried to set setting in application.yml of my spring project

```
spring:
   jackson:
      date-format: "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss a"
   serialization:
      write_dates_as_timestamps: false
```

but even I am getting same issue.

I also tried to override the existing @JsonSerialize and @ JsonDeserialize classes, where I explicitly serializing LocalDateTime into string and that's working. But I do not want to do any customized code.

Please help me, why its happening...

Comment: Are you sure about the format with a big "D"?

Comment: Yes its working in my dropwizard version. also working with my custom changes